# Java regexp matcher - multiple groups

Tags: java, regex

I am using Pattern and Matcher to create a regexp which will extract the 6 values from within the li tags I have below:

```
 <ul class="Bold">                                <li class="ball-orange">2</li>                                <li class="ball-orange">10</li>                                <li class="ball-orange">11</li>                                <li class="ball-orange">15</li>                                <li class="ball-orange">22</li>                                <li class="ball-orange">39</li>                            </ul>
```

I.e. the result of the regexp needs to be groups with 2, 10, 11, 15, 22, 39.

I have the following code:

```
Pattern numbersPattern = Pattern.compile(".*(<li class=\"ball-orange\">([0-9]{1,2})</li>).*");
Matcher matchNumbers = numbersPattern.matcher(mainBlock);//mainBlock is the string I quoted above which contains all the li's
System.out.println("Numbers Match? " + matchNumbers.matches());//this returns true
System.out.println(matchNumbers.group(2));//returns 39, i.e. second group but for the last li

//this loop never gets entered!!!
while (matchNumbers.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
    //System.out.println("group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

So it matches the very last li as you can see from the comments, **but it does not enter the while (matchNumbers.find()) loop**. I.e. I want `(<li class=\"ball-orange\">([0-9]{1,2})</li>)` to be found 6  times, and output in the loop, but it is not.

I am following the tut here - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html#groups-inside-groups.

Why is the loop not being entered, and how can I get the groups of li's to be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're matching the whole string eagerly (anything + li + anything), that's why `matches() == true`. If you want all, just remove the `.*` parts, because `.find()` will find your pattern multiple times, first at position ~25 and then ~60, etc...:

```
    String mainBlock = "<ul class=\"Bold\">                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">2</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">10</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">11</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">15</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">22</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">39</li>                            </ul>";
    Pattern listPattern = Pattern.compile("<li class=\"ball-orange\">([0-9]{1,2})</li>");
    Matcher matcher = listPattern.matcher(mainBlock);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("whole thing: " + matcher.group()); // or group(0)
        System.out.println("number: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
```

> whole thing: <li class="ball-orange">2</li>
>   number: 2
>   whole thing: <li class="ball-orange">10</li>
>   number: 10
>   whole thing: <li class="ball-orange">11</li>
>   number: 11
>   whole thing: <li class="ball-orange">15</li>
>   number: 15
>   whole thing: <li class="ball-orange">22</li>
>   number: 22
>   whole thing: <li class="ball-orange">39</li>
>   number: 39

Note: you never need to put a group around the whole regex, capturing group 0 is by definition the whole match, that's why numbering starts at 1.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try exactly that (removing .* as you have), it does not match anything. "Numbers Match? " + matchNumbers.matches() returns false.

Comment: That's because the pattern is not matching the whole string, and it shouldn't, because you are looking for parts. Read the javadoc of [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) and [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()). Usually you either use one or the other, they do different things: validation vs extraction. In the code in the question `matches()` consumes the whole string, so `find()` is trying to start from the very end of the input.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really help me - I have read the documentation, and am still having this issue. I know matches is validation, and the other extraction. That doesn't solve the problem here though.

Comment: I ran the code I wrote and updated the answer with the output, that's the output you seemed to have expected based on the question.

Comment: OK, thanks very much - that expression works fine, I think when testing it first time I was using an incorrect var name.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex `.*(<li class=\"ball-orange\">([0-9]{1,2})</li>).*` will consume entire string because of `.*` at start and end. If you want to enter loop consider using only `(<li class=\"ball-orange\">([0-9]{1,2})</li>)` part.

Or even better instead of regex use proper tool: HTML parser like jsoup:

```
String mainBlock = "<ul class=\"Bold\">                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">2</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">10</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">11</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">15</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">22</li>                                <li class=\"ball-orange\">39</li>                            </ul>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(mainBlock);
for (Element el : doc.select("li.ball-orange")){//pick all <li class="ball-orange"> tags
    System.out.println("li tag: " + el);
    System.out.println("value in li : " + el.text());
}
```

Output:

```
li tag: <li class="ball-orange">2</li>
value in li : 2
li tag: <li class="ball-orange">10</li>
value in li : 10
li tag: <li class="ball-orange">11</li>
value in li : 11
li tag: <li class="ball-orange">15</li>
value in li : 15
li tag: <li class="ball-orange">22</li>
value in li : 22
li tag: <li class="ball-orange">39</li>
value in li : 39
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try Jsoup, looks like a good solution here. I would still like to know how to get the regexp to work though.

Comment: `matches()` checks if entire string can be matched by regex and if it does this string will be consumed by Matcher which leaves nothing left to iterate on. But even if you wouldn't consume entire string via `matches()` method you would do it with in first `find()` because of `.*` which are greedy. So remove these `.*` from start and end of your regex. Also get rid of `matches()` method, or replace it with `find()` (and then call `reset()` on matcher to reset its cursor at start).

Answer (score -1):

you have to change your regex to `"\<li class=\"ball-orange\"\>\d{1,2}\</li\>"` use \d instead [0-9]

```
Pattern numbersPattern = Pattern.compile("\<li class=\"ball-orange\"\>\d{1,2}\</li\>");
        Matcher matchNumbers = numbersPattern.matcher(mainBlock);//mainBlock is the string I quoted above which contains all the li's
        System.out.println("Numbers Match? " + matchNumbers.matches());//this returns true
        System.out.println(matchNumbers.group(2));//returns 39, i.e. second group but for the last li

        //this loop never gets entered!!!
        while (matchNumbers.find()) {
            System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
            //System.out.println("group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
        }
```

Comment: You were on the right track, answer questions with explanations on what you changed, how it didn't work and how it works now. It took me a few seconds to spot the differences, always point out what you've modified when posting code if it's not full obvious.

Comment: I am sorry  but I was hurry